# libotify / notify-send: body text is not printed if it contains '<' or '>'

Tags: libnotify, notify-send

I am on Linux Mint 18.1, MATE.

I am using the notify-send command to visualize the name of keys (such as `<enter>`), while sending them to the current window via a python script.For about two weeks, notify-send has shown a weird behavior. I know the basic syntax in bash is `notify-send [OPTIONS] <summary> [body]`.

### Basic problem

When executing `notify-send -t 0 '<enter>' 'text body'`, everything looks fine:
[image]

However, when trying to print the key name in the message body with `notify-send -t 0 'Summary' '<enter>'`, I get:

[image]

The same happens with `notify-send -t 0 'Summary' '<'`,  `notify-send -t 0 'Summary' '>'` or `notify-send -t 0 'Summary' \<`

Any ideas why the body text is printed blank if it contains < or > ?

---

### Workaround (fails)

I have tried to use a python module istead:

```
from gi.repository import Notify
Notify.init("App Name")
Notify.Notification.new("Summary","<enter>").show()
```

But the result is the same as in picture 2 above.

---

### Additional info:

When trying `zenity --info --title='Summary' --text='<enter>'` in bash, I get an error message:

`(zenity:4952): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to set text '<enter>' from markup due to error parsing markup: Error on line 1 char 24: Element 'markup' was closed, but the currently open element is 'enter'`

And instead of the text `<enter>`, the opening info dialog has the surprising text: `All updates are complete.`

Comment: For the `zenity` issue, try adding `--no-markup`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [notification spec](http://www.galago-project.org/specs/notification/0.9/x161.html) says that *body* can include simple markup, so any tags inside "<...>" will be removed and interpreted if possible. For example, `"<b>hello</b>"` will show the word in bold.

You can use the standard html entity mechanism and show a `<` with `&lt;` and 
`>` with `&gt;` giving, for example,

```
notify-send 'Summary' '&lt;enter&gt;'
```

If you prefer you can just use a multiline summary, eg:

```
notify-send 'Summary
<enter>'
```

Comment: dynamically: `notify-send 'Summary' "$(recode ascii..html <<< "$body")"`